# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "apikey" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, smtp, laravel-8, swift-mailer

Tengo un problema con el envío de correo con laravel 8 y sendgrid, al envíar el correo me muestra lo siguiente:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "usuario@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response

Mi archivo .env tiene la siguiente configuración

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=usuario@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=usuario2@anpeseweb.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Donde **usuario@gmail.com** es mi usuario de la cuenta de sendgrid y **SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx** es la API KEY  generada por Sendgrid

Probe el envío de correo desde mi servidor con curl

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "destinatario@gmail.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "usuario2@anpeseweb.com"},"subject": "Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}]}'
```

Y el correo se envío sin problema. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución, estaba muy confundida respecto a  los valores que llevaban  *MAIL_USERNAME* y *MAIL_PASSWORD* y por fin buscando encontre que para:

*MAIL_USERNAME* = **apikey** así  literalmente la palabra **apikey** que hace referencia a la cuenta de  correo electrónico con la que se creo la cuenta de sendmail

*MAIL_PASSWORD* = con la cadena generada por sendgrid

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, así los demás nos enteramos que esta es la solución